# packaging and deploying java desktop application with embedded database

Tags: netbeans, desktop-application, derby, executable-jar

I created a simple desktop application that uses embedded database(derby) from netbeans.After adding two entries into the table inside the ide and running it again works perfect.But when i double click the executable jar file outside the ide an empty database is shown what might be the reason? I would also like to know how to make this run on client machine.I tried adding the jar and lib files into a folder and converting it into a rar file but i don't find the jar file after extracting.I am new to this and any help would be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common reasons why you find that you are getting an empty database unexpectedly:

1. You are saying ';create=true' and using a relative database name, meaning that you are giving Derby permission to create the database fresh if it doesn't exist, and then your Derby system home directory is changing from run to run, so you are ending up creating new copies of the database each time, in different current directories.
2. You are using a different username when you connect to the database. Since the username with which you connect implicitly specifies the schema in which your tables reside, using a different username causes you to see a whole different set of tables, or, depending on how you look at it, an empty database.

Regarding jars and rars and such, the crucial thing is to manage your CLASSPATH properly. You need to have the Derby code in your CLASSPATH at runtime. There are a large variety of ways to make this happen, so you'll need to be quite explicit about the particulars of your situation in order for others to give you much help.

Comment: thank you that was a lesson..so can i package the db file along with the jar file? because as you said in the first case when the db file is along with the jar in the same folder the db works fine

Comment: Yes you can pre-package a database with your application. The specifics vary depending on whether the database is read-only or updatable. If read-only, start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdvlp19700.html If the DB is updatable, you'll want to have your installation procedure un-zip it to a local folder at startup. The derby-user mailing list is a good way to contact other developers who have done this or similar things.